# Eclipse doesn't allow me to set Dynamic Web Module version to 3.0, jumps back to 2.3

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have a Maven project and I need the Dynamic Web Module  3.0, but Eclipse tries to automatically  set it back to 2.3 and this gives an error, because it cannot do it.

What is the problem and why Eclipse trying to set it back to 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

There are some facets that prevents you from setting web module 3.0, may be Java version, but make sure you have used dynamic web project feature when created a project. And try to reset some facets before you are setting the new one. Also if you have a `web.xml` make sure you use correct dtd version.

Comment: My project is maven, how can i stop this problem

Comment: In the maven plugin that shuld have in Eclipse specify the version you use and rebuild the proejct.